# Intent within onUtteranceCompleted method not working

Tags: android, android-intent, onutterancecompleted

I am trying to implement an intent to take the user back to the home screen once the TextToSpeech function completes, but it isn't working, and I'm not sure why. Here is my code:

```
public void playText(){     
    String text = typeNewMessageEditText.getText().toString();
    HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "completed");
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashRender);        
}


@Override
public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
    if (utteranceId.equals("completed")){   
                Intent displayMainActivity = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(displayMainActivity);
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is not working? does the it crash?

Comment: The TextToSpeech function completes, and does nothing, like onUtteranceCompleted is not being called or something...

Comment: put a log inside onUtteranceCompleted. Log.d("TEST", "onUtteranceCompleted"); and see if the logcat log it.

Comment: I've stumbled upon some info in other posts that shouldn't have worked because in Eclipse, the SetOnUtteranceCompletedListener method is said to be deprecated, but I went ahead and set this method in onInit, and now my intent works within OnUtteranceCompletedListener....??? How does a deprecated method still work? Anyways, thanks for the help Hoan!